# Prove a vector calculus identity

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vectors, vector-fields

Let $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ have smooth boundary $\partial V$. Suppose $f, g, \mathbf{J}$ are differentiable on $V \cup \partial V$, with $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{J} = 0$ in $V \cup \partial V$, then prove that

$$
\int_V (f\ \mathbf{J} \cdot \nabla g + g\ \mathbf{J} \cdot \nabla f)\ dV = 0.
$$

*My attempt*: The integrand is $\nabla\cdot(fg\ \mathbf{J})$, so by Divergence Theorem, the integral above is equal to

$$
\int_{\partial V} fg\ \mathbf{J}\cdot d\mathbf{S}.
$$

Furthermore, $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{J} = 0$, so $\mathbf{J} = \nabla \wedge \mathbf{A}$ for some $\mathbf{A}$, so the integral is equal to

$$
\int_{S}fg\ \nabla\wedge\mathbf{A}\cdot d\mathbf{S}.
$$

How to show that this is $0$?

Comment: By $\nabla \wedge \mathbf A$ do you mean cross product?

Comment: $\nabla \wedge \mathbf{A} = \nabla \times \mathbf{A}$ is the curl of $\mathbf{A}$

Comment: You are making some topological assumption in assuming $J=\nabla\times\mathbf{A}$.  Anyway, what you wanted is not true for, e.g., $V=(1<r<2)$ and $\mathbf{J}=r^{-2}\mathbf{e}_r$, $f=g=r$.

Comment: Your $\nabla \cdot \textbf{J} = \delta(\textbf{r}) \neq 0$?

Comment: for arbitrary V that is not true. It will only happen if $\mathbf{J}\cdot\nabla(fg) = 0$.